# method() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given in pagination decorator action

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a problem doing a paginator about an action decorator in django rest framework and I can't find the solution, the question is that it gives me the following error:

get_response_data () takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

```
class InterfacesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Interfaces.objects.all()
    serializer_class = InterfaceSerializer
    pagination_class = PostPageNumberPagination

    def get_response_data(paginated_queryset):
        data =[ {
            'id_interface': interface.id_interface,
            'id_EquipoOrigen': interface.id_EquipoOrigen_id,
            'EquipoOrigen': interface.id_EquipoOrigen.nombre,
            'LocalidadOrigen': interface.id_EquipoOrigen.localidad,
            'CategoriaOrigen': interface.id_EquipoOrigen.categoria,
            'id_PuertoOrigen': interface.id_PuertoOrigen_id,
            'PuertoOrigen': interface.id_PuertoOrigen.nombre,
            'estatus': interface.estatus,
            'etiqueta_prtg': interface.etiqueta_prtg,
            'grupo': interface.grupo,
            'if_index': interface.if_index,
            'bw': interface.bw,
            'bw_al': interface.bw_al,
            'id_prtg': interface.id_prtg,
            'ospf': interface.ospf,
            'description': interface.description,
            'id_EquipoDestino': interface.id_EquipoDestino_id,
            'EquipoDestino': interface.id_EquipoDestino.nombre,
            'LocalidadDestino': interface.id_EquipoDestino.localidad,
            'CategoriaDestino': interface.id_EquipoDestino.categoria,
            'id_PuertoDestino': interface.id_PuertoDestino_id,
            'PuertoDestino': interface.id_PuertoDestino.nombre,
            'ultima_actualizacion': interface.ultima_actualizacion,
        } for interface in queryset]

        return data

    @action(methods=['get'], detail=False, url_path='registros-data-table', 
    url_name='registros_data_table')
    def registros_data_table(self, request):
        queryset = Interfaces.objects.all()

        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            data = self.get_response_data(page)
            return self.get_paginated_response(data)

        data = self.get_response_data(queryset)
        return Response(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `get_response_data` expects 1 positional argument, but you are calling it with two - the object `self` and list `page`.

```py
data = self.get_response_data(page)
```

Here is a shorter example code showing this issue:

```py
class Example:
    def test(*args):
        print(args)

    def run(self):
        self.test("my string")


Example().run()
# (<__main__.Example object at 0x10320b160>, 'my string')
```

To fix this issue, you can change the function signature to include `self` positional argument:

```py
def get_response_data(self, paginated_queryset):
```

Comment: I now get the following error added the self as an argument in the get_response_data function:

name 'queryset' is not defined

Comment: `queryset` is an instance variable in your `InterfacesViewSet` class. So when you are in `get_response_data` function, you can access it with `self.queryset`.

Comment: Also, when you are in `registros_data_table` method, you are setting `queryset` method variable instead of `self.queryset` instance variable.

Comment: Thank you very much it worked perfectly with the self.queryset

Comment: I remain doubtful with your last comment, I did not understand, although it worked with the first thing you told me